# AS2 : How to remove text formatting from input

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

How to remove text formatting from input :

```
k = <TEXTFORMAT+LEADING%3D"2"><P+ALIGN%3D"CENTER"><FONT+FACE%3D"Trebuchet+MS"+SIZE%3D"38"+COLOR%3D"%23CCCCCC"+LETTERSPACING%3D"0"+KERNING%3D"0">22<%2FFONT><%2FP><%2FTEXTFORMAT>&
```

and I need only

```
k = 22
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the text from that HTML (XML) code, you can :

**1 - Use an XML object like this for example :**

```
var k:String = '<TEXTFORMAT+LEADING="2"><P+ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT+FACE="Trebuchet+MS"+SIZE="38"+COLOR="%23CCCCCC"+LETTERSPACING="0"+KERNING="0">22<%2FFONT><%2FP><%2FTEXTFORMAT>';

var xml:XML = new XML(k);

trace(xml.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild);     // gives : 22
```

**2 - Use a TextField :**

```
this.createTextField('text_field', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
text_field.html = true;
text_field.htmlText = k;

trace(text_field.text);     // gives : 22

text_field.removeTextField();
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: In flash is a bug. I make only new document create new input then copy and pase - and i have clear vartables